# org-mode table element selection with blanks

Tags: org-mode, org-table

TL;DR: How do you send a list of elements from a table, **including** blank cells, to an elisp function?

I have the table below with points on exam questions in columns 2-4. The second row contains the **maximum** number of points for each question. The student rows contain the actual points received. I want to compute the maximum **possible** sum for a student, to be updated while I grade the questions.

I have written an elisp function that takes two lists as arguments and does the necessary computations. However, the standard selection argument ignores blank elements. In the function call below, the function will receive the (fontified) lists '("3" "4") '("6" "4" "6") and '("6" "2") '("6" "4" "6"), respectively. I need a selection where each blank element is kept as, e.g., fontified "". Is that possible?

Have tried google and the org manual to no avail.

```
#+NAME: PTS
|           | Q1| Q2| Q3|     | Max |
|-----------+---+---+---+-----+-----|
|           | 6 | 4 | 6 | Sum | Sum |
|-----------+---+---+---+-----+-----|
| Student 1 | 3 | 4 |   |   7 |  13 |
| Student 2 | 6 |   | 2 |   8 |  12 |
#+TBLFM: @3$6..@>$6='(sum-with-defaults '(@0$2..@0$4) '(@2$2..@2$4)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Untested]

The [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Calc.html#Formula-syntax-for-Calc)[1] says that an `E` mode string after the formula should keep empty fields as empty strings in a range (there is also an `N` mode string which forces all fields to be numbers - if the numeric conversion fails, the field is treated as the number 0):

```
#+NAME: PTS
|           | Q1| Q2| Q3|     | Max |
|-----------+---+---+---+-----+-----|
|           | 6 | 4 | 6 | Sum | Sum |
|-----------+---+---+---+-----+-----|
| Student 1 | 3 | 4 |   |   7 |  13 |
| Student 2 | 6 |   | 2 |   8 |  12 |
#+TBLFM: @3$6..@>$6='(sum-with-defaults '(@0$2..@0$4) '(@2$2..@2$4)));E
```

[1] The [section after the one I linked](https://orgmode.org/manual/Formula-syntax-for-Lisp.html#Formula-syntax-for-Lisp) talks about "Formula syntax for Lisp" and mentions that modes can be used for such formulas as well.